# Swift animate UITableViewCell expanding height constraint

Tags: ios, swift, animation, tableview, constraints

I have a TableView with a **static cell** inside which I would like to expand when a button has been pressed. There is a **container view** inside the cell, the **constraints** have been set up correctly but I am not sure how to actually animate the cell expanding as it requires me to refresh the **table view** to update the constraints and expand the cell.

Currently when I call `expandContainerView` it doesn't animate, because I am calling `self.tableView.reloadData`.

Here is the code that I have used to expand the cell

```
@objc private func expandContainerView(notification: NSNotification) {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.containerHeightConstraint.constant = 410
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

And here is my height for each row at index code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: what actually you tring to do? Do you have expand collapse tableview or there is an another concept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try without an animation block:

```
containerHeightConstraint.constant = 410
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can only reload cell which you want to expand using below code. I added in the `didSelectRowAt` but you can add same code in button action method.
Set expandCell variable to true for changing height of cell when reloading.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     // Expand View 
     self.expandCell = true 
     self.tableView.beginUpdates()
     self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
     self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

You need specify height to expand cell view else it will show default height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == expandRowIndex && self.expandCell {
         return 200
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**Note : No need of animation for this. Expansion of view animation at time of reloading cell**

Comment: Just to add, `UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic` can have weird effects on the cell being expanded. If you use `UITableView.RowAnimation.none` instead, it will be animated and will behave normally. Very strange!